# Difficulties with File URI on 7.0

Tags: android, file, android-permissions, file-uri

To be as short as possible, I'm using the following code to upload a file to DropBox:

```
PackageManager manager = getPackageManager();
                                File f = new File(getContext().getExternalFilesDir("diabetix"),"TESTINTENT.xml");
                                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                                intent.setType("text/*");
                                intent.setPackage("com.dropbox.android");
                                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, FileProvider.getUriForFile(getContext(),"david.projectclouds.MainActivity",f));
                                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "title"));
```

The intent opens up nicely, but it doesnt save the file and outputs an error(not in the log, the dropbox app does this).

Since I have a similar issue with OneDrive, I decided to print out my file URI(getting NoFileSpecified error with OneDrive).

content://david.projectclouds.MainActivity/file/diabetix/Temp.xml

This is my URI. I looked at some examples and it seems like it is correct. The file also exists when using a FileExplorer app.

I'm using this to show permissions:

```
    public void requestReadWritePermissions(){
 // Here, thisActivity is the current activity
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
            +ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)!=PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)||(ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE))) {

            // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
            // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
            // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.
            Toast.makeText(this, "App needs this permission to run", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        }else{
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                        REQUEST_WRITE_PERMISSIONS);
            System.out.println("PERMISSION_GRANTED");

            }
        } else {


            // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                    REQUEST_READ_PERMISSIONS);

        }
    }
```

The same code worked fine on a phone under 7.0(think it was 5.0).

Any ideas? Can someone look over my permissions? Removing them outputted the same error. It only requests one "Request to ACCESS media,files,photos.." Should it show the "write media etc." too?

Answer (score 1):

Do you catch the requestPermission result? When you call requestPerimission, you also need to override the onRequestPermissionsResult, like below:

```
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE: {
                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    //granted. here you need to call the method, which uploads file to DropBox
                }
                else{
                    // no granted. Handle this somehow.     
                }
                break;
            }

        }
    }
```

Please read [this](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) tutorial:

Answer (score 1):

With Android 7.0+ there is a new policy. You have to use a `FileProvider`. [See here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html) for more details.

In short you would define it in the `AndroidManifest.xml` and create a new `resources.xml` under the `xml` folder (probably need to create one). There you define the paths which should be shared with other apps.

From the Docs

```
<manifest>
    ...
    <application>
        ...
        <provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.mydomain.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            ...
        </provider>
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

The `paths.xml` under the `xml` folder.

```
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
</paths>
```

To get the new URI you can use the `#FileProvider.getUriForFile` method like this

```
FileProvider.getUriForFile(yourContext,
        "your.package.name" + ".provider",
        yourFile);
```

The URI looks like this

`content:///fileprovider/pathname/actualPathToFile`

Finally you have to add the flag `Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)` to your `Intent`. That's it.

Comment: Thank you for your time. As you can see in my code I am using FileProvider. However my paths.xml was different. Can you tell me what I should use as path="." ? Do I leave it as just the period? If not what do i add?

I also used intent.setFlags() to add that flag in your answer. But to no avail.

Comment: @Nephilim See the docs here https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html . There are different path types. The `.` character is just being convenient. In my example it shares every file on the external path e.g. sd card.

Comment: Thank you. I'll leave it as `` . `` until I manage to fix this error.